# Self-Destructing Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm looking for ways to design a self-destructing Cocoa application. The idea is to detect at launch if the application is being retro-engineering (which is always done in several attempts) and delete/corrupt it in case of. Of course, a zealous hacker could re-download and retro-engineer the destruction process, but it would make it really annoying and painful!

For checking code integrity, hashsums on the executable should do the trick.

With regards to the corruption process, I am pretty sure that an application can't edit its bundle while running.
I have one idea :

-spawning a "middle application" dedicated to destruction, launching it while quitting the first . Would it work ?

-Would spawing a Shell Script(which would wait to for application to terminate) before quitting do the trick ?

Any ideas are welcomed !

EDIT : With regards to Cocoaster link :

1.Stripping debug symbols : it is very easy to trace "verification" methods, even without explicit methods name, mostly by looking for NSString calls (@"validated", @"license")

2.PT_DENY_ATTACH : there are ways to attach anyway, but breaking on ptrace() and modifying return value (and if I could find this in my basic retro-engineering training, anyone can).

3.Checking checksum, quitting otherwise : that's exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid : it is easy with gdb to trace the call to [NSApplication shouldTerminate:]) and modify the test (or the valid MD5 string)to pass it. The whole point is that instead of just having to reload gdb, the hacker will need to download/install it again (thus making the process REALLY time-consuming).

Imagine this :

1.At launch time, the mainApplication creates a shell/bash script which would be something like :

```
 wait(decent time)
 rm /*Dynamic Application Path*/Contents/MacOS/exe
```

or better :

```
  sed -i 's/a/b/g' /*Dynamic Application Path*/Contents/MacOS/exe
//Will completly screw the code
```

2.If checksum fail , launch script and terminate application quietly.
My question is : is NSTask Application-dependant (can I launch a NSTask and quit the application who launched it)?

Comment: You can encrypt your datafiles with the hash from the executable. Or use a boot loader that does this. When the exutable is altered, the data will not be readable anymore. But when you think of something like this, so will the hacker.

Comment: Silly question: do you have a link ? Googling "boot loader cocoa" doesn't help :S

Comment: No, not specifically. You have to make one yourself. I used to use such a 2 phase bootloader under DOS ages ago. But I would focus on the answers below

Comment: Eat your canned & encrypted DB if the checksum fails.  Use the DB to provide control flow.

Comment: you could also not all shouldTerminate, but crash hard with 1/0 for instance.

Comment: @HotLicks Your idea seems really interesting, could you develop a bit more (in terms of implementation) ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that this will gain you anything. If I were trying to manipulate such a program and saw it self-delete te first thing I would do is run a new copy without write permissions for its directory. Seems like significant work, with a chance of hurting legitimate users, for minimal inconvenience to an attacker. What are you actually trying to conceal or prevent? Maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: Permissions is a good defense, and I'm not sure we can undo that programmatically at launch (can we ?)
The main point is to screw with the hacker, I'm well aware of the fact that every protection will be cracked :D

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you're looking for?

http://www.seoxys.com/3-easy-tips-to-prevent-a-binary-crack/

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/283683-detecting-if-you-re-being-debugged.html

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/109505-detect-debugger.html